# DocFX generating documentation for a project in a different folder

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, docfx

I have the structure of the file:

[image]

I want to use DocFX to create documentation of my project but my problem is file docfx.json. My project is in another folder like `C:\Test\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1` not in src folder in docFx, when I try to change localization docFx don't find the project. How do I set this path?

I introduced the correct path but still doesn't work.

```
"metadata": [
{
  "src": [
    {
      "files": [
        "src/**.csproj"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"metadata": [
{
  "src": [
    {
      "files": [ "src/**.csproj" ],
      "src": "../ConsoleApp1"
    }
  ],
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/938ab1b27547625d17d612422d3650e3d67e374f/Documentation/docfx.json#L8) from DocFX's own documentation site.